# apache2 server keeps timing out was working fine 3 weeks ago

Tags: apache-2.2

error.log is empty, and when i connect to this domain, i get time out error.

```
NameVirtualHost  23.23.23.23
<VirtualHost  23.23.23.23>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www/
RewriteLog /var/log/rewrite
RewriteLogLevel 9

        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
ErrorDocument 404 /hi.html
ErrorDocument 403 /hi.html
ErrorDocument 500 /hi.html

        </Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/">
  AllowOverride AuthConfig FileInfo Options
  # The Options below is an example. Use what you deem is necessary.
  Options MultiViews SymLinksIfOwnerMatch IncludesNoExec
  IndexIgnore *
  Order allow,deny
  allow from all
ErrorDocument 404 /hi.html
ErrorDocument 403 /hi.html
ErrorDocument 500 /hi.html


</Directory>
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
    LogLevel crit
</virtualhost>
```

I've resetted my server. DNS is working fine. however whenever it times out, there should be some error recorded but nothing!! so i dont know how to fix this problem.

Answer (score 1):

start gathering some stats for the server. right now you are quite blind.

install [munin](http://munin.projects.linpro.no/) and plot charts of load / memory usage / number of processes / nummbe of apache processes and served pages.

you can also install [sysstat](http://pagesperso-orange.fr/sebastien.godard/) to get raw numberic stats. regardless of your distro you should be able to find both in standard repository.